# Python is adding "" to string when using it to create a concatenated string if read in from file

Tags: python, string, variables, string-literals

I am just starting to learn python and trying to build a cURL API request in python and can get the headers to work when I create a string directly in python, but not if I read in some of the data from a file.

I want to not hard code the API key, but pull it in from a file.

The following works

```
apikey = 'apikey'
headers = {
'x-api-key': apikey,
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
)
```

This gives an output of:
**{'x-api-key': 'apikey', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}**

However if I read it from a file

```
with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "api.txt"), "r") as f:
apikey = f.read()
```

This gives an output of:
**{'x-api-key': "'apikey'", 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}**

This has a set of "" around the variable. The main difference I can see is that the first code variable is a literal and the second a str.

If I do a print(apikey) then neither have the "".

Any ideas how to correct this so that I can read from a file and not end up with the extra ""?

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Are there quotes around the value in the file?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to read the file with `json.load`?

Comment: There is a single quote mark around the apikey in the file as these are required for the api request. The double quote marks are not in the file.